# Как записать результат в эту же таблицу через UPDATE в PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Я не много не понимаю что делаю не так, у меня есть таблица accounts и там есть значение  которые нужны чтобы рассчитать и записать в столбец result_for_the_month.

вот мой sql запрос:

```
UPDATE accounts SET result_for_the_day = (SELECT (number_of_cars * rated_energy * general_tariff) * 24 FROM accounts)
```

Ошибка:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000
```

Если использовать Insert Into то он добавит новые строки с результатом а мне это не надо.

вот таблица:

```
id number_of_cars rated_energy general_tariff  result_for_the_day
1       2              3.25           4               
2       5              2.4            4 
3       7              1.9            3            
4       8              3.4            3 
5       6              5.6            3
```

сама формула (number_of_cars * rated_energy * general_tariff) * 24
Результат в result_for_the_day

Comment: Формулируйте задачу, а не только свои попытки её решить. Не задавайте несколько вопросов в одной теме. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-sql/1035#1035)

Comment: Хорошо, изменил

Comment: ```UPDATE accounts SET result_for_the_day = (SELECT (number_of_cars * rated_energy * general_tariff) * 24 FROM accounts a2 where a2.id=accounts.id)``` Добавить условие в подзапрос:)

Comment: спасибо, я просто не оконца понимал какое условие ему надо

Answer (score 0):

Если всё вычисление опирается только на эту же текущую строку - то подзапрос вовсе не нужен. Просто:

```
UPDATE accounts SET 
  result_for_the_day = number_of_cars * rated_energy * general_tariff * 24
where ...
```

Comment: Ну тогда вообще никакого запроса не надо - generated column, и всё.

Comment: да, в том числе. Но тут уже надо погружаться глубже в задачу - надо ли соблюдать эту формулу в дальнейшем или это нужно только для начальных данных